# EBS volumes Storage Analysis

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, storage

I have created a ec2 instance and attached 4 ebs volumes, gp2=3gb, gp3=3, io1=4gb, io2=4 and mounted it.

I have installed postgres source code on it and the database location path is `/usr/local/postgresql/pgsql/data`.

I have create a test table name testdb with 2 million  sample entries, but it does not shows the space consumed on ebs volumes that I have attached.

Whatever tables i am creating all the storage is been utilize by the root volume which comes by default when we create an instance and it shows 34% used.

I want to know how can move or  change the location, so that the database which I have created with 2 million entries, it should reflect in any of the ebs-volumes which I have attached to an instances.

Also, how can I check what data is being consume by the ebs-vol?

The 4 volumes which i have attached only shows 2% used, How to check what 2% has been used for and i want table which i am creating in PSQL database to be store in any volumes by default automatically without storing in root volume. so that I can make an analysis which EBS vol is good out of 4 with low cost use.

[image: Photo]

I'm unable to find what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You probably want to use tablespaces.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

Comment: I have successfully created the tablespace and created db inside it and it shows the data used by the ebs_vols.   Is there any way where the data should automatically go inside any 4 ebs volumes and consume the storage? , My Goal is to make an analyse which EBs volume does it use while I store or create a database with records, Does it go to any specific EBS vol, or the data goes or divides in all the 4 volumes